# Preventing an app from exiting immediately?

Tags: iphone

How can I prevent an application from exiting immediately? If the user press the home button while the application is saving a picture to the photo album, only a part of the picture is saved!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can put code in your App Delegate's

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Function to attempt to quickly finish saving the picture and notify the user that they prematurely quit the application, but there's nothing you can do to prevent a user from pressing the home button and quitting your app.

Comment: To add, the OS puts you on a timer in the applicationWillTerminate method. If you take longer than the timer, then your app will be hard terminated. There is no way around this.